# How to show rectangle playing cards with a perspective view on a table?

Tags: perspective, cocos2d-js, skew

I am working on 2D card game on cocos creator.

I wanted to simulate perspective view for the game. I created a table image with a perspective view. Now I wanted to show the card with perspective view when they are on the table.

My playing card images are rectangles. I wanted to convert them to trapezoids.

To do this it seems I have to scale down from the top edge. 
The node can be skewed but does not offer any feature to do something like this.

Can anyone suggest how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2d-html5 v3.9 and older you could apply perspective transformations with following:

```
node.getCamera().setEye eye_x, eye_y, eye_z
```

It worked only in WebGL mode though, and was already marked "deprecated".

Somewhere between v3.10 and v3.12 camera support was removed, and new (faster) renderer was introduced.

At the moment only affine transformations are supported, that means no perspective transforms in latest Cocos2d-js yet.

Comment: I guess then, there is no way to actually get a perspective transform. Is there a way to adjust the corner points of a sprite or something similar that can simulate the perspective view. I am new to cocos creator, what is the standard way of doing something like this?